# IBM MQQueue Put method is taking time to put the messages into queue

Tags: ibm-mq

We are using IBM MQ Client 7.5.0.5 version to establish the connection with MQ server to get and put the messages into queues.
Most of the time system took milliseconds to put the messages into the queue. But, sometimes it is taking 7 to 20 seconds to put the messages[MQQueue.put(message, MQPutMessageOptions)] into the queue.

Anyone faced same kind of issue? What could be the possible cause of this issue?

Comment: Slow put times could be caused by many reasons: network latency between MQ client and queue manager, queue manager disk slow down, CPU exhaustion on either the client or queue manager, number of putting and getting processes connected to the queue, large message size.  7.5.0.5 is very old. 7.5 was released in 2012 and went out if support in 2018. The 7.5.0.5 maintenance was released May 2015 and the last version 7.5.0.9 was released September 2018.  I would suggest you move to a supported version of MQ. 9.1, 9.2, and 9.3 are currently supported, 9.1 will probably be out of support in 2023.

Comment: Anything that takes 20 seconds or so makes me think of connect timeouts. Is the 20 second how long ONLY the put takes, or is this also including a connection as well.

Comment: Does any other work using the queue manager have any problem?   For example try local runmqsc.  If nothing else affected then I reckon it is a network problem.  Try a ping from the client to the host and see what that is like.  If other work in queue manager affected then it is likely to be queue manager problem (unless all work comes in over client).   Check the error logs

Comment: @MoragHughson, Thanks for the response.
It's ONLY the PUT that is taking time. A connection has already been established at the time of starting the application and we used to put the messages whenever we got a request from the user.

Comment: @JoshMc, Thanks for your response. The queue manager was managed by the customer, so we don't have much information on what is going on with the queue manager. But from our side, we checked the CPU utilization and it looks good. The network also seems good when we did the check. Actually, this slowness happened randomly[sometimes it's taking seconds to PUT the message, but after minutes it's taking milliseconds to PUT the message in the same queue manager]. 
So, finally we planned to upgrade the MQ version.

Comment: @colinpaice, Thanks for your response. The only other work we do with that queue manager is to GET the message from it and we don't see any issues in getting those messages[But, we are also not sure how long the queue manager took to put the message from the customer side]. Since the queue manager was managed by our customer we didn't get a chance to see the error logs.